# Why is HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync sending a GET request?

Tags: .net, http-post, http-get, botframework, http-status-code-405

I'm using a pretty standard implementation of the HttpClient to send a POST request. I have an object, serialized into JSON, given to a StringContent object then POSTed using HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync.

I have both a LAN server and a public server. 2 applications on the LAN, 1 on the public. The LAN server hosts a Jenkins instance and an intermediary application trying to send this POST request. The public server hosts a Bot Framework bot which is trying to collect the POST data.

Jenkins posts information to the intermediary application regarding builds using the Notification plugin. This application requests extra information about the build using Jenkins JSON API. I grab the relevant Jenkins data, put it in an object, Serialize to JSON and try to send it to the Bot.

```
var botMessage = new JenkinsBotMessage(notification, svnData);
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("{BOT URL}");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept
        .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    HttpResponseMessage response =
        await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/jenkins", botMessage);

    //....
}
```

The Bot responds with a 405 saying it doesn't allow GET requests. Which is correct, the Bot only has a POST method. But the intermediary should be sending a POST.

So the question is **WHY** would the intermediary application be sending a GET request to the Bot when the API is intended to send a POST? I've dug into the HttpClient to see what happens inside of PostAsJsonAsync and I can't see anything in there that would convert the request to be a GET, so is it possible I could be missing something from the server set-up?

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: __PostAsJsonAsync sending a GET request__ - what does it actually mean?

Comment: The question is why is it sending a GET when the method is clearly meant to send a POST...

Comment: @toadflakz I've added the question now, apologies if it wasn't clear.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh It means that (see code added above now) when 'client.PostAsJsonAsync' is called and sent to my bot's server, the server responds with a 405 error saying that the GET method is not allowed. But the method is clearly intended to ONLY send POST requests, thus I am expecting it to.But it isn't, the way the Bot server responds is telling me that the client is sending a GET but there isn't any clear indication as to why.

Comment: @Liam'L'Wilson, The data is being serialized twice. first time when you manually serialize it and second when the method serializes the string content object passed. This is all that is needed : `client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/jenkins", botMessage);`

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using DirectLine to talk with your bot?

Comment: @EzequielJadib I hadn't even seen it until now but it might be a good option, I'll look into it now. I'm not sure if it will actually fix this problem but it's worth a try.

Comment: @Nkosi fixed that now, will edit main post as I'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: For sure the `HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync` is performing a `POST` request. It's only an extension method based on `HttpClient.PostAsync` method. I think that you should show us the exact payload (serialized data) and which API call you try to use (URL and Jenkins API reference). I suspect that the issue relates to the endpoint.

Comment: @Liam'L'Wilson Just so you know you  weren't crazy, I'm facing same issue of PostAsJsonAsync sending a get request (or at least that's what the exception is saying).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Ezequiel Jadib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90081/ezequiel-jadib) for a solution to the problem. It's managed to get around the issue I was having rather than actually answering the question as such but still saved me slaving hours away trying to fix it.

Using DirectLine now to communicate with the bot from the intermediary application. It has seemed a bit slow in getting the message across to the bot but I can send the JSON through as a message and parse it in the Bot from the Messages controller.